# Join tables and count between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

Im having a hard time understanding how to join tables, so sorry for my question =D

Alright. I have two tables: `users` and `user_traning`.

`user_traning` adds users training with the following columns:

`id, user_id, date, type, notes` etc

The `users` tables updates the `user_last_login` row with the last login datetime.

My thought is to count how many (new) rows there is in `user_training` between `users.user_last_login`, with help from `user_traning.date`.

I have been trying like this:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_traning
    JOIN users
    on users.user_id = user_traning.user_id
    WHERE users.user_id = '2' and user_traning.user_id ='2' between 
users.user_last_login and now()
```

So i can show a little badge on the page, how many new sessions that has been addad since last visit =)

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: `users.user_id = '2' and user_traning.user_id ='2'` you don't need to check this twice, as both `user_id` cols are already equal because of the `JOIN users on [...]` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are alomost there but you have a small syntax issue at the end, it should be as

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_traning ut
JOIN users u
on u.user_id = ut.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = '2' 
and ut.user_id ='2' 
and ut.date between u.user_last_login and now()
```

UPDATE : From the explanation provided in the comment.

Consider the following 2 tables

```
mysql> select * from user_training ;
+------+---------+---------------------+
| id   | user_id | date                |
+------+---------+---------------------+
|    1 |       1 | 2015-04-14 16:35:01 |
|    2 |       1 | 2015-04-14 16:35:10 |
|    3 |       3 | 2015-04-14 16:35:18 |
|    4 |       4 | 2015-04-14 16:35:25 |
|    5 |       2 | 2015-04-13 16:37:16 |
|    6 |       2 | 2015-04-14 15:57:26 |
|    7 |       3 | 2015-04-14 15:27:38 |
+------+---------+---------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from users ;
+---------+------+---------------------+
| user_id | name | user_last_login     |
+---------+------+---------------------+
|       1 | AA   | 2015-04-14 16:34:10 |
|       2 | BB   | 2015-04-14 16:34:10 |
+---------+------+---------------------+
```

From the above sample data there are 4 entry in the `user_training` table which happened after last login of `user_id = 2`

Now we can get those data as

```
select * from user_training ut 
left join users u on u.user_id = ut.user_id 
join ( 
   select user_id,user_last_login from users where user_id = 2 
)x on ut.date >=  x.user_last_login  ;
```

This will give you

```
+------+---------+---------------------+---------+------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
| id   | user_id | date                | user_id | name | user_last_login     | user_id | user_last_login     |
+------+---------+---------------------+---------+------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
|    1 |       1 | 2015-04-14 16:35:01 |       1 | AA   | 2015-04-14 16:34:10 |       2 | 2015-04-14 16:34:10 |
|    2 |       1 | 2015-04-14 16:35:10 |       1 | AA   | 2015-04-14 16:34:10 |       2 | 2015-04-14 16:34:10 |
|    3 |       3 | 2015-04-14 16:35:18 |    NULL | NULL | NULL                |       2 | 2015-04-14 16:34:10 |
|    4 |       4 | 2015-04-14 16:35:25 |    NULL | NULL | NULL                |       2 | 2015-04-14 16:34:10 |
+------+---------+---------------------+---------+------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

So to get the count we can just use the `count` in the query as

```
select count(*) from user_training ut 
left join users u on u.user_id = ut.user_id 
join ( 
  select user_id,user_last_login from users where user_id = 2 
)x on ut.date >=  x.user_last_login
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it is not working the way i want it to (i think). I want to count entries made by other users as well, user with ID 1,3,4,5... etc, that is made after my (User ID 2) last login. Joining is hard =)

Comment: Please share some sample data into the question and expected output.

Comment: Im trying to count new rows in `user_traning` since last login from `users.user_last_login where users.user_id = 2`. Table `user_traning` saves data from all users with a date column, `user_traning.date`. I thought your answer would do the trick, but i end up with `0` as a result :/ Thanks in advance and hope it made sense =)